# How to run capistrano tasks over lossy connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano3

Is it possible to run a capistrano task over a lossy connection?

E.g. if the internet drops out or your disconnect wifi, it will resume the command/task when you're back online.

I am using capistrano v3x.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that Capistrano doesn't have the ability to retry and continue failed tasks such that a lossy connection would work.

When I've encountered this issue, I set up a deployment box on the same network as the target server, then I use SSH and tmux or screen to maintain a persistent connection from which to deploy. If your connection to the deploying box drops, the screen/tmux session will remain active and continue the deployment, and you can reconnect to that box and reopen that session (`screen -r` or `tmux a`).